# Video.js, Setup Guide, Include Global Variable

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

In the [Video.js Setup Guide](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html#toc_1), there is an instruction that allows users to turn off Google Analytics; however, I am unsure of exactly how to follow the instruction and want to make sure I am doing so, correctly.

The instruction reads:

> We include a stripped down Google Analytics pixel that tracks a random
>   percentage (currently 1%) of players loaded from the CDN. This allows
>   us to see (roughly) what browsers are in use in the wild, along with
>   other useful metrics such as OS and device. If you'd like to disable
>   analytics, you can simply include the following global before
>   including Video.js:

`window.HELP_IMPROVE_VIDEOJS = false`

Where does that variable go? In its own, separate `script` tag?

Here is what I have:

```
<head>
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
        window.HELP_IMPROVE_VIDEOJS = false;
    </script>
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0.2/video.js"></script>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
</head>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's the problem?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I am just super new. Want to make sure that it works and that I am doing it 'right'.

Comment: HELP_IMPROVE_VIEDOJS  or HELP_IMPROVE_VIDEOJS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is correct.

If you look at the end of the CDN script, the last section checks for the presence of that variable and generates a random number to determine whether to ping Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find where `help_imporove_videojs` is being used in the cdn source...
Maybe this could help you debug if help_imporove ever being used

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "HELP_IMPROVE_VIEDOJS", {
  get: function() { 
    debugger; // trace the call stack
    return false
  }
});
```

They also mention

> We include a stripped down Google Analytics pixel that tracks a **random percentage** (currently 1%) of players loaded from the CDN

So 1% of all the people will actually help to imporove videojs. It means that the source code is 99% the same